# How correct is the Southern colloquialism "y'all" in correct English grammar?

Tags: grammar

Have I capitalized and punctuated correctly above?  (Note the space between last letter and question mark in title? (We'll, it was there!))

Comment: It's unclear what you r question is? Is it the one in the title (how correct is "y'all") or is it the one n the body (is it correctly punctuated/capitalized)?

Comment: If I were to read *y'all* in any formal situation, I would find it quite off-putting at best.  I am, however, from BC Canada, where *y'all* is frowned upon even in colloquial speech.

Comment: @Anonym: it's frowned upon in formal speech and writing in the south. It's totally appropriate in speech less formal than 'very formal'. It doesn't appear in newspapers and journal articles (formal writing) mostly because those don't encourage the use of any 2nd person.

Comment: @mitch huh? It's very common in formal speeches, from religious sermons to academic lectures to legislative discussions. You are right about formal writing, probably also because if you do use second person, you presume a single reader.

Comment: @guifa I would say that that is a sign that those sermons and lectures are more informal than usual because they're using "y'all".

Comment: @mitch if you define the use of *y'all* as automatically making something informal, then by definition all Southern speech is necessarily and automatically informal which is pretty obviously false. We use *y'all* in all spoken registers, formal included — it does not connote informality as it might in other English speaking regions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. "Y'all" is a contraction for "you all", and so you have placed the apostrophe correctly to account for the missing letters. (You will frequently see the incorrect form "ya'll", but this doesn't expand correctly.)

Also be aware that "y'all" is **always** plural. Never use "y'all" to refer to a single person! You wouldn't use "you guys" or "all of you" to refer to one person, so don't use "y'all" either.

Comment: I've heard claim that some southerners _do_ use "y'all" as a singular and then "all y'all" as the plural, but I've never heard those kinds of southerners in my life (is that a Texas thing?).

Comment: As a born and bred Alabamian, I can say that I have never heard a native Southerner use "y'all" in the singular. It's possible that a transplanted Southerner might use it that way until corrected, though, since it seems to be the standard usage in TV and movies made about the South by people who aren't from there.

Comment: I can confirm that y'all and all y'all are used more or less interchangeably for the plural in Central Florida.

Comment: (Texan POV) I had a college Latin professor who claimed y'all could be used as a singular.  I told him "that's a common Yankee misperception." He said "Well I'm going to go home and check the OED."  Next day in class I asked him what it said.  "It basically said that's a common Yankee misperception," he replied. It can be confusing because it can be used to refer to parties not present - he and his wife had moved to the area, and his boss had seen him and said "How are y'all settling in?" The clear Southerner implication is that his not-present spouse is included in the query.

Comment: I suspect the "1 in 100" exception mentioned in [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%27all) is a simple case of "people using the wrong word or otherwise being fumble-tongued in casual conversation."

Answer (score 1):

Y'all be is never grammatically correct

Comment: never? *Y'all be trippin'* is quite fine AAVE (habitual aspect)

Answer (score 0):

Y'all is never grammatically correct in UK English. It isn't used. It would be understood however, and recognised as American English.

'You' would be used instead, to represent the 'collective you' (there is no way to distinguish the collective from the individual 'you' in UK English, as far as I know. I'm a native English speaker).

Meaning: You
'The one or ones being addressed'
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to a colloquial usage, perhaps a regional dialect. There are may of these.  So in Somerset you will hear "Where's he to?" for "Where is he?".  And if the shop assistant says "that'll be ten pounds ninety nine pence, my lover", she is not claiming previous carnal knowledge with you.  The issue is not whether it is correct British or American English.  It might be said to be 'non-standard'.  Or so I thought.  Until I checked the Cambridge English online dictionary, which says:

> **pronoun**  US informal...(you all)

'informal' has nothing to do with grammar or meaning.  It is a term of disapproval.  Formal English is just an approved style for communications which you want to be taken seriously.

Merriam Webster, a (perhaps 'the') US dictionary, says much the same.

> pronoun ... variant of you all ... *chiefly Southern* ... YOU usually used in addressing two or more persons.

There is no hint here of the condescension of the word 'informal'.  I think, though I cannot prove it, that it is more often used in speech than in writing other than fiction and Facebook.